# Div scroll animation

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, parallax

I'm trying to make a div follow my scroll events and after my scrolling stops the divs kinda bounce, similar to this website:

http://thespaceinbetween.co.nz

I'm looking for jquery plugins that I might use to create an effect similar to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a plugin named **NICESCROLL** --> https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll

**[See the Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/yWnfD/)**

You need to use `bouncescroll:"true"` option in your code. See the below code for details

```
jQuery("html").niceScroll({
    bouncescroll: "true",
    cursorcolor: "#000000",
    boxzoom: false,
    autohidemode: false,
    cursorwidth: 10
});
```